# is it possible to connect bluetooth device, without pairing them in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, external-accessory

The question is not for BLE device, its just normal bluetooth device.

currently my code works like this,
I call the function :

```
[[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] showBluetoothAccessoryPickerWithNameFilter:nil completion:^(NSError *error)
        {

        }];
    }
```

and it opens the popup with list of available Bluetooth device, then i click on my desired device and get an object and go ahead.

Is there any way that i can skip this picker step and directly get an object of my device?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to connect without pairing first. The first time, you must have the user pair with the device either from the Settings app or from the picker. After the first pairing, however, you can skip the picker and get an `EAAccesory *` for your accessory, if the accessory is already connected to the iOS device. Here is how you can query the list of connected accessories:

```
NSArray<EAAccessory *> *connectedAccessories = [EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager].connectedAccessories;
for (EAAccessory *accessory in connectedAccessories) {
    // Implement needed filter to recognize your device.
    // You can use for instance accessory.protocolStrings
    // The MAC address is available with [accessory valueForKey:@"macAddress"]
}
```

With the EAAccessory framework you can't initiate a connection to a device programmatically. For subsequent connections, you can have your device reconnect to the last connected device (if you control the firmware). This will trigger the `EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification` if your app is in the foreground, otherwise it will queue the notification and update the list of connected accessories.

Comment: Could you clarify how the firmware can accomplish an automatic subsequent connection? I work directly with firmware engineers and would like to provide the capability for users to not have to go into the Settings App and manually connect to the accessory before using the iOS application I am working on.

Comment: @Audible Well the relevant documentation is part of the MFi program, so I can't give any details publicly. But if you or the firmware team have access to the MFi Accessory Interface Specification, you'll find a starting point in section 52.4 (in the revision R27). Depending on what Bluetooth chipset is used in the product, there may also be a function to do it in the libraries that come with the chipset.

Comment: I definitely understand the strict MFi guidelines, however, this is a great answer, thanks! I have access to the MFi and will look at the specific section you referenced and I will work with the firmware engineers and the chip manufacturer to try and get this settled. Much appreciated.